# I couldn't stop thread with if statement

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, semaphore

That's my code below

```
class SecondTextViewTask extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (semaphore.availablePermits() == 0 && firstTextDigit <= 9 && secondTextDigit <= 9) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                secondTextDigit++;
                                secondDigit.setText(String.valueOf(secondTextDigit));
                                Log.e("Test== ", "" + secondTextDigit + " " + semaphore.availablePermits());
                                if (secondTextDigit == 9) {
                                    semaphore.release();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

First I start semaphore with 0 and after the secondTextDigit(integer) arrives 9 semaphore release and This task must stop. But when I use `Log.e`, I can see on my `Logcat` secondTextDigit=10 and my semaphore=1. At this situation how if statement work and go inside? Where is my logic mistake?
(secondDigit is TextView.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `if` statement checks this:

```
semaphore.availablePermits() == 0 && firstTextDigit <= 9 && secondTextDigit <= 9
```

This can be valid of `secondTextDigit == 9`.

You then call `secondTextDigit++`. If `secondTextDigit == 9`, then `secondTextDigit` becomes 10.

Finally, your condition that releases the semaphore is `secondTextDigit == 9`, which will be false if `secondTextDigit` is 10, and you get stuck.

Comment: But when the number is equal to 9, semaphore.release(); and after semaphore.availablePermits() = 1. this condition also break if statement. @Billy Brown

Comment: @ZpCikTi I'm not sure how the rest of your code works, but it looks like you should be using `semaphore.acquire()` instead of just checking `semaphore.availablePermits == 0`. As to the race condition: say that your first 8 threads have terminated (`secondTextDigit == 8` now), then you start two more threads. One increases it to 9, then the other takes over and increases it to 10. At that point both threads see 10 and skip the final `if` statement. I will add this to my answer.
EDIT: I misread the location of your `Thread.sleep()`. Technically the race condition still applies but probably not.

Comment: Okay, you are right. I am gonna find other solution. Thank you a lot @Billy Brown